# How do I assign limited console program access to IIS 6?

Tags: iis-6

Let's say I have a simple console program to fetch a list of files given the folder name. I want to call the console program using PHP code on a site that is running on a unique Windows user account (ie not the default web user account). Is there a way I can allow the Windows account access to the console program without giving it blanket access to cmd.exe? I'm working with IIS 6 on Windows 2003 Server.

**Update:**

Here's some code I've tried using popen()

```
$reg_cmd = '"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"' ;
$error = '';
$handle = popen($reg_cmd, 'r');

if (!$handle){
    $last_error = error_get_last();
    $error = $last_error['message'];
}
else{
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $result .= fread($handle, 2096);
    }
}
pclose($handle);
```

$error ends up containing either:

popen("C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe",r) [function.popen]: Result too large

OR

popen("C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe",r) [function.popen]: No such file or directory

I've no idea why the error message is inconsistent. The results were even less promising using proc_open().

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `proc_open()` instead of `exec()`?

From version 5.2.1 `proc_open()` no longer requires you to give access to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I've updated the question with some code. proc_open() didn't produce a handle either so the stdout and stderr objects were not accessible. BTW the code works ok if I give rights to cmd.exe (which is what I'm avoiding)